# Get Distinct row from table A based upon a value from table B

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help adjusting the below proc to have the ability to return a result from the organization table when doing a search from the service table. The organization can have several services listed in the services table keyed off of the organization_id. one org, many services.
The current proc in place was used to search for the organization and return that row OR it would return all organizations if all the fields are blank. I want to change it so that I can still maintain that but have it return the organization if a service is searched for.

```
SELECT
    organization_id,
    organization_nm,
    contact_nm,
    phone_nr,
    email_ad,
    last_upd_dt,
    update_frequency_cd
FROM ORGANIZATION
WHERE
    organization_id = CASE 
        WHEN @organization_id = 0 THEN organization_id 
        WHEN @organization_id IS NULL THEN organization_id 
        ELSE @organization_id END
    AND organization_nm LIKE CASE 
        WHEN @organization_nm IS NULL THEN organization_nm 
        ELSE '%' + @organization_nm + '%' END
    AND update_frequency_cd = CASE 
        WHEN @update_frequency_cd = 'x' THEN update_frequency_cd 
        ELSE @update_frequency_cd END
    AND operator_id = CASE 
        WHEN @operator_id = 0 THEN operator_id 
        WHEN @operator_id IS NULL THEN operator_id 
        ELSE @operator_id END
ORDER BY organization_nm
```

I did this inner join and it get's me the results I want, but I am at a loss on how to incorporate it into the proc. I've been trying many ways to get it to work but did not want to muck up my question with those attempts. Any help making the two pieces fit would be much appreciated OR if I can be schooled on the proper/easier way to make this work.

Here is the inner join I did that gets me the results I am looking for when searching for just a service.

```
SELECT 
    org.organization_id,
    org.organization_nm,
    org.contact_nm,
    org.phone_nr,
    org.email_ad,
    org.last_upd_dt,
    org.update_frequency_cd,
    service_nm
FROM dbo.ORGANIZATION AS Org
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT organization_id AS orgId, service_nm
FROM dbo.RECYCLE_SERVICE
WHERE service_nm = 'my service'
) AS serv
ON  Org.organization_id = serv.orgId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note - User community needs to acknowledge original posts...when editing others answers

Try:

```
SELECT
    org.organization_id,
    org.organization_nm,
    org.contact_nm,
    org.phone_nr,
    org.email_ad,
    org.last_upd_dt,
    org.update_frequency_cd,
    service_nm
FROM dbo.ORGANIZATION AS Org
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT organization_id AS orgId, service_nm
FROM dbo.RECYCLE_SERVICE
WHERE service_nm = 'my service'
) AS serv
ON  Org.organization_id = serv.orgId 
WHERE
    organization_id = CASE 
        WHEN @organization_id = 0 THEN organization_id 
        WHEN @organization_id IS NULL THEN organization_id 
        ELSE @organization_id END
    AND organization_nm LIKE CASE 
        WHEN @organization_nm IS NULL THEN organization_nm 
        ELSE '%' + @organization_nm + '%' END
    AND update_frequency_cd = CASE 
        WHEN @update_frequency_cd = 'x' THEN update_frequency_cd 
        ELSE @update_frequency_cd END
    AND operator_id = CASE 
        WHEN @operator_id = 0 THEN operator_id 
        WHEN @operator_id IS NULL THEN operator_id 
        ELSE @operator_id END
ORDER BY organization_nm
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you for responding!